# Is there a similar way to read integer pairs from stdin to vector<pair<int,int> > in C++

Tags: c++

I am wondering if there is a way as slick as the following

```
copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(),back_inserter(v));
```

to copy pairs of `int` into a `vector<pair<int,int> >` when the input is given in pairs in the order of their appearance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this – but you need to write your own `operator >>` for the pair class first. This operator is the whole secret of the above call. Its actual implementation depends on the format of your int pairs.

Comment: :o really ? Nice! I thought, that this uses .push_back or something. +1

Comment: could you please give an example of working code? many thanks

Comment: @Qiang Li: Trivial.  `template<class A, class B> istream& operator>>(istream& in, pair<A, B>& val) { return in >> val.first >> val.second; }`

Comment: @Quiang: I don’t know how your number pairs look so I really can’t. But @ephemient has given a basic example assuming that the numbers are separated by whitespace or newline.

Comment: @Kiril: it does, but that’s independent of the type.

Answer (score 4):

[`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) could be used.

```
copy(boost::make_zip_iterator(
         boost::make_tuple(istream_iterator<int>(cin),
                           istream_iterator<int>(cin)),
     boost::make_zip_iterator(
         boost::make_tuple(istream_iterator<int>(),
                           istream_iterator<int>()),
     back_inserter(v));
```

Comment: wow... It's funny that such a low-level language as C++ is the first I encounter this concept implemented in...

Comment: @Pavel: because C++ is a low-level, may things are possible. It's just that usually you don't know where to look :) On the other hand, `zip` is pretty well-known, especially in functional programming.